# Task generated T-SQL shows unknown property IsMemoryOptimized

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, maintenance-plans

I have modified a Maintenance plan on SQL Server 2008 using SSMS 2014, particularly Reorganize index task - I have added another two databases for this task.

When I wanted to check if the T-SQL is OK, the `View T-SQL` button shows the error:

> unknown property IsMemoryOptimized

Could (should?) that be fixed somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer so as to close this question:

Most probable reason that error has been witnessed in SQL server 2014, could be you are not updated to the latest cumulative updates.

> unknown property IsMemoryOptimized

has been reported as bug, may not be somewhat similar to you're situation, but CU has been suggested.

However, for now, please try to make the changes using the SQL server 2008/R2 and see if that works.

Comment: I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v 12.0.2000.8. But downloaded it just a moth ago with SQL Express. What is the fastest way to update it? Using this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3075950 ?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008 SSMS it works.